# Update date in Excel sheet trough VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet where customers have option to pay by installments like in term of 1, 3, 6 and 12 monthly Payments, and the installment period is not fixed (like for some clients it is 3 months while for others 6 months)

So if a Customer Pays today. 5/10/2016 has Frequency of 6 Month I click a paid button and it Adds 6 month to the next Due Date (which is 01/10/2017)

Second thing is payment term should change when client pay. for example (if client have to pay in 6 months and he pay some amount after 2nd month then the payment term should be 4 month rather than 6 months)

Is there a way to do it through macros VBA Excel?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done without VBA, using a formula.

First, I suggest you change the text values from "6 month" to numbers. It is easy to format a number to show with the word "month" after it, using custom format `0 \mo\nt\h`. Then you can use a formula like

```
=EDATE(B2,A2)
```

If you don't want to change the text values, you can do it in-formula with a substitute function like this:

```
=EDATE(B2,SUBSTITUTE(A2," month","")+0)
```

Start in row 2 and copy down.

If you really need this in VBA, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.EDate()` to the same effect.

Comment: Yes. this is useful when TERM has only 1 value. Each cell in TERM column has 4 values like a list or array. So when i change value in list formula disappear.

Comment: In your screenshot, each cell in TERM has only one value. If that is NOT what you want to do, please edit your question and provide sample data for ALL the scenarios you want to solve.